# Cómo crear un template por el cual debe de pasar cada ruta antes de presentar el template requerido inicialmente

Tags: javascript, angularjs

No se si me explico bien, quiero crear una ruta con un template que se muestre antes de presentar el template requerido, ahí es donde quiero mostrar la publicidad.

Ejemplo: al dar clic en cualquier enlace que me redireccione al templete de la publicidad y al pasar unos segundos que me redireccione al template requerido originalmente al dar clic.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si eso sea lo mejor para tu sitio web. Recuerda que también debes tener en cuenta la experiencia de usuario y no creo que a un usuario le guste mucho ver publicidad cada que seleccione un enlace.

Puedes buscar en google estrategias para añadir publicidad a tu sitio web y empaparte lo suficiente del tema para hacerlo lo más amigable posible, pero si es de vital importancia que lo hagas como lo describes, puedes usar https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state y podrías jugar con el evento `$stateChangeStart`

Comment: Gracias por responder Cristian, estoy creando un sitio web de noticias y quiero implementarlo cada vez que accedan a una noticia, se puede hacer con el ngRoute nativo de AngularJS o es obligatoriamente con el ui-router ? Si puedes darme un ejemplo de cómo implementarlo te lo agradecería mucho. Todavía no me llevo muy bien con JavaScript y AngularJS lol.